# add participant into chatrooms using ejabberd

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm new in android. i want to create chat app using ejabberd xmpp server with smack 4.1 api.

i created chat_room using command now i want to add participant into that chat groups.

here is the screenshot

[image]

in above image there are three rooms created but there is no any participants.

how can i add participants?

Comment: what command? xmlrpc or http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly add users to a chat room but you can send invitation to other to join your chat room. You need to use the `send_direct_invitation` command for that.

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/ejabberdctl/muc-admin/#invite-several-users-to-a-muc-room

Comment: can we add permanent member into chat room? i mean when i close the application i am not able to get incoming message from that chat room. in sort i want add functionality like whatsapp group. any suggestion?

Comment: You can try Multi-User Chat Subscriptions for this. You will need to set "Allow subscription" parameter to the chat room. The docs for this are available at 
https://blog.process-one.net/xmpp-mobile-groupchat-introducing-muc-subscription/ 
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/